# In Node.js, how can I make a parent object emit all of a child object's events?

Tags: node.js, events, coffeescript, socket.io, eventemitter

Let's say I have an object like so (using coffeescript):

```
class Client
  constructor: (socket) ->
    @id     = socket.id
    @socket = socket
    # some other initialization here...
```

Now, any time @socket emits something, I want the client object to mimic it by emitting the same event.  I can't think of a better way to do this than to just watch for every single event being emitted by @socket and emitting it manually within the Client class, i.e.:

```
class Client
  constructor: (socket) ->
    # ...
    @socket.on('disconnection', onDisconnect)
    @socket.on('message', onMessage)

  onDisconnect: ->
    this.emit('disconnection')

  onMessage: (data) ->
    this.emit('message', data)
```

I know there has to be a better way, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Check this out, Matt: https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/wildemitter

Wildcard event handling...does that help?

Comment: That's good to know about, Jason, but unfortunately I don't think that will with socket.io emitting events.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? (Untested.)

```
class Client

  constructor: (socket) ->
    # ...
    for event in ['disconnect', 'message']
      @socket.on(event, => @emit(event, arguments))
```

Comment: What I'm really trying to accomplish is not having to know what events the socket might be sending from within the Client class.  So ideally, Client would forward all socket events regardless of what they are, i.e. no explicit event names in a loop.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think you can do that with the standard `Emitter` stuff, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Monkey-patch `@socket` object emit:

```
class Client
  constructor: (socket) ->
    @reEmit(socket)

  reEmit: (ee)->
    oldEmit = ee.emit
    ee.emit = (args...)=>
      @emit(args)       
      oldEmit.apply(ee, args)
```